# Add and Remove attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

My problem is when I click submit, it should add the `box` class only for empty fields. But my code adds the `box` class for both filled and unfilled fields.

```js
function validate() {

  var a = document.forms["Form"]["uname"].value;
  var b = document.forms["Form"]["number"].value;
  var c = document.forms["Form"]["mail"].value;

  if (a == null || a == "", b == null || b == "", c == null || c == "") {
    ['uname', 'mobNo', 'mail'].forEach(function(ids) {
      document.getElementById(ids).style.border = "1px solid red";
    });
    return false;
  } else if (!a.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/)) {
    document.getElementById('uname').className = 'box';
    return false;
  } else if (!b.match(/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/)) {
    document.getElementById('mobNo').className = 'box';
    return false;
  } else if (!c.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+)+(\.[\w-]{2,4})?)$/)) {
    document.getElementById('mail').className = 'box';
    return false;
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return validate()" action="" id="form_id">
    <fieldset>
      <label>NAME:</label>
      <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="fields">
      <label>MOBILE NUMBER:</label>
      <input type="text" name="number" id="mobNo" class="fields" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
      <label>EMAIL:</label>
      <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" class="fields">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your first `if` clause is false: `||` = logical or, `&&` = logical and -> `if (a==null || a=="",b==null || b=="",c==null || c=="")` should be `if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c==""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in your if else conditions

You can validate your form this way.

```
   function validate() {
      var a = document.forms["Form"]["uname"].value;
      var b = document.forms["Form"]["number"].value;
      var c = document.forms["Form"]["mail"].value;

      var validation=true;

      if ((a == null || a == "")||(!a.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/))) {
        document.getElementById('uname').className = 'box';
        validation=false;
      } else{
        document.getElementById('uname').className = '';
      }

      if ((b == null || b == "")||(!b.match(/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/))) {
        document.getElementById('mobNo').className = 'box';
        validation=false;
      } else{
        document.getElementById('mobNo').className = '';
      }

      if ((c == null || c == "")||(!c.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+)+(\.[\w-]{2,4})?)$/))) {
        document.getElementById('mail').className = 'box';
        validation=false;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('mobNo').className = '';
      }

      return validation;
    }
```

Here is a working codepen link,
http://codepen.io/nadirlaskar/pen/rjOEJQ

Answer (score 1):

in:

```
if (a==null || a=="",b==null || b=="",c==null || c=="")
```

`,` operator will do nothing; it returns last comparison:

```
(c==null || c=="")
```

please fix as

```
if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c==""))
```